# Delay in file transfer using TCP socket

Tags: sockets

I am using TCP socket to transfer file from server to client in small chunks. Many times the data transfer is delayed or stopped. What is the reason for the delay, is there any way to optimise the transfer.Thanks in advance

Comment: This can depend on the OS, the physical network, other machines on the same network, your machine and your code, where you should suspect the latter the most.

Comment: This is probably due do [NAGLE algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). Disable it with `TCP_NODELAY` socket option or better yet try to write larger packets to have less overhead.